# Magento 2 : Sales Order Grid table is empty but data exist in sales_order

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, adminhtml, order-grid

**Magento 2.3.3 CE**

Sales Order Grid table is empty but data exist in ***`sales_order`*** and ***`sales_order_item`***.

Earlier I have thought that some module issue so I have disabled all but still after running reindex and clear cache its empty.

It seems order details are not added to the ***`sales_order_grid`*** table. Does anyone faced this issue ?

Tried these commands already.

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex   
bin/magento c:f
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: have you disabled the Asynchronous indexing under Store > Configuration > Advance > Developer > Grid Settings ?

Comment: Nope its enabled.

Comment: Try to disable, clear cache and reindex, Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Comment: Ok, I'm adding this as answer, Please accept the answer and upvote, So it will help to others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disable **Asynchronous indexing** under

> Store > Configuration > Advance > Developer > Grid Settings

Clear cache and reindex, Hope this will work or you.

Comment: And what for Cloud Commerce version?

Comment: I had to enabling it instead of disabling.